# How do I reorder Y-Axis in chronological order in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a ridge plot using the `ggplot` function and I would like to display it in chronological order.

My timestamp is in character and in the form of "Apr-2022" (%m-%Y).

```
ggplot(ridge_plot_final, aes(x = Wage, y = fct_inorder(timestamp))) +
  geom_density_ridges_gradient(scale = 4) +   # for both axes to remove unneeded padding
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off") + # to avoid clipping of the very top of the top ridgeline
  theme_ridges()
```

```
dput(df)

class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-13331L), groups = structure(list(timestamp = c("April-2022", 
"April-2023", "August-2022", "December-2022", "February-2023", 
"January-2023", "July-2022", "June-2022", "March-2022", "March-2023", 
"May-2022", "May-2023", "November-2022", "October-2022", "September-2022"
), .rows = structure(list(1:880, 881:1760, 1761:2640, 2641:3520, 
    3521:4400, 4401:5280, 5281:6160, 6161:7040, 7041:8051, 8052:8931, 
    8932:9811, 9812:10691, 10692:11571, 11572:12451, 12452:13331), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -15L), .drop = TRUE))
```

When I tried to plot, the order seems to be in a mess. Can anyone advise how to reorder my dates? Here is what is currently looks like:

[image]

Comment: Please share your data using `dput(df)`?

Comment: You may need to keep `timestamp` as a date object and then use labels in `scale_x_date` to format the date, but it would be easier to check with a reproducible example we can run.

Comment: @Quinten I shared my dput (df) results

Comment: @JordanOng This is not the full `dput`, as it can't be used in this format and `Wage` is also missing.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to first `arrange` the data before piping into `ggplot`, then we can use `fct_inorder` as you have. So, we can convert the `timestamp` to a date inside the arrange, so that we can keep it as a character. Here, I assuming that you want the earliest date at the top. If not, then we could just remove the `desc` inside the `arrange` statement.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggridges)

ridge_plot_final %>%
  arrange(desc(lubridate::my(timestamp))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Wage, y = fct_inorder(timestamp))) +
  geom_density_ridges_gradient(scale = 2) +   # for both axes to remove unneeded padding
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off") + # to avoid clipping of the very top of the top ridgeline
  theme_ridges()
```

**Output**

[image]

**Data**

```
set.seed(123)
ridge_plot_final <- data.frame(timestamp = rep(c("April-2022", 
                                             "April-2023", "August-2022", "December-2022", "February-2023", 
                                             "January-2023", "July-2022", "June-2022", "March-2022", "March-2023", 
                                             "May-2022", "May-2023", "November-2022", "October-2022", "September-2022"), 4),
Wage = c(runif(60, 500, 10000)))
```